# python bisection search exercise

Tags: python, bisection

I have been looking at it for a while and I cannot see what is wrong with my bisection search. If I run it, it says 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison'. Could anybody have a look and see what is wrong below? Thank you!

```
#Write a function called in_bisect 
#that takes a sorted list and a target value 
#and returns the index
#of the value in the list if it’s there

def in_bisect(t, word):

    if len(t) == 0:
        return False

    middle = len(t) // 2

    if t[middle] == word:
        return middle

    elif t[middle] > word:
        return in_bisect(t[:middle], word)
    else:
        return in_bisect(t[middle:], word)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'peach', 'watermelon']

    in_bisect(fruits, 'banana')
    in_bisect(fruits, 'ewf')
```

Comment: You have to exclude middle when you recurse to avoid infinite recursion.  You forgot to exclude it from the last case.

Comment: btw, you `return middle` instead of `return t[middle]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine what happens when the list length is 1. Then the middle will be 0. If now the  final `else` case is the actual one, the recursion will get the same list (size) again, with the same result... infinite recursion.

Solution: add one to `middle` as at that moment you already know that `middle` itself is no longer a candidate:

```
else:
    return in_bisect(t[middle+1:], word)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use loop here instead of recursion since Python cannot convert tail recursion into loop and has very low limit on recursion depth.

I would also check wheither `word` is in `t` and return `False` otherwise.

```
def in_bisect(t, word):
    def iterator(start, end):
        # loop will terminate when exactly start = end - 1
        while start < end - 1:
            middle = (start + end) // 2
            if t[middle] == word:
                return middle
            elif t[middle] > word:
                end = middle
            else:
                start = middle + 1
        # here we need to check wheither the last element in the list is the one we search for
        return start if t[start] == word else False

    # if len(t) is zero, our inner function would raise IndexError so we check it explicitly
    if len(t) == 0:
        return False
    return iterator(0, len(t))
```

Comment: Thanks for your code! I didn't know Python as low limit on recursion, and I haven't seen a def inside of another def – it's helpful to see how it can be written this way.

Comment: Default limit is 1000 AFAIK but you can change it if you like. Anyway, Python developers prefer imperative paradigm. They moved functional stuff like `reduce` from `builtins` to `functools` module and are not going to support tail recursion optimization so, in my opinion, it is better not to use functional style in Python :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'peach', 'watermelon','dog','cat']

def in_bisect(t, word):
    # cheks if the word is in the list 
    if word not in t:
        return False 
    if len(t)==0:
        return False
    low=0
    high=len(fruits)
    #loop will when the value is found 
    while True:
        mid=(low + high)//2

        if t[mid]==word:

            return mid,t[mid]
        if word in t[:mid]  :
            high=mid
        else:
            low=mid
def test():
    print(in_bisect(fruits, 'apple'))
    print(in_bisect(fruits, 'banana'))
    print(in_bisect(fruits, 'kiwi'))
    print(in_bisect(fruits, 'dog'))
    print(in_bisect(fruits, 'ewf')   )
    print(in_bisect(fruits, 'banana'))
    return 'Test completed sucssfuly'
print (test())
```

Comment: Adding some explanation to the code might help us understand the written code better.